# when are modules redeclared vs aliased?

Tags: ocaml

I have a very hard time understanding in OCaml when modules and types are aliased versus redeclared.

For example, to use a module A in a file `x.ml` it seems like I have several path:

- `open X.A`, not great as I open all of the thing
- `module A = X.A`, am I redeclaring here? Will this create all sorts of problem?
- use https://github.com/johnyob/ppx-open to bring a Rust-flavored `use X::A`
- `module B with A := A` the destructive module substitution, but by doing that I lose access to the module A

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `open A` nothing is [defined or declared](https://ocaml.org/manual/modules.html#sss:mexpr-open), this *module expression* just allows you to use elements from the opened module without referencing the module name. This is a pure namespacing operation that has no reflection in runtime. In other words, it only affects the typing environment.

In `module A = X.A` you're defining (since 4.02) a module alias. So nothing is redeclared and `A`, as well as all its components, could be used in the same place where `X.A` and its components are expected.

The `ppx_open` extension gives you better control over what you want to alias in the current module. In the end, it rewrites to

```
open struct 
  type t = Other.t
  module Foo = Other.Foo
  let foo = Other.foo
end
```

So it is still an `open` expression and nothing is redefined.

The last example, `module B with A := A`, is not a valid module expression.

> Am I missing something?

I think you're missing the information about *sharing constraints*. This is what matters, e.g.,

```
module type X = sig type t val x end
module Foo : X = struct type t = int let x = 42 end
module Bar = Foo (* [Bar.x; Foo.x] typechecks *)
module Bar : X = Foo (* [Bar.x; Foo.x] no longer typechecks, they have distinct types *)
module Bar = struct include Foo end (* [Bar.x; Foo.x] .. typechecks *)
module Bar : sig include module type of Foo end = struct include Foo end 
(* [Bar.x; Foo.x] doesn't typecheck *)
```

As you can see from the examples above, if you do not specify the signature, OCaml tries to ascribe [the strongest](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/papers/xleroy-manifest_types-popl94.pdf) signature possible, with the only exception of the `module type of`, which explicitly prevents signature strengthening, i.e., produces an unstrengthened signature. It doesn't mean that it will erase aliases, e.g.,

```
# module X = struct type t = int let x = 42 end;;
module X : sig type t = int val x : int end
# module type X_of_X = module type of X;;
module type X_of_X = sig type t = int val x : int end
```

Notice that the aliasing information is not erased, but it is not strengthened to `type t = int = X.t`, but it is not necessary because the types of `X.t` and `Y.t` are known to be equal as they are aliases to the same type, e.g.,

```
# module Y : sig include module type of X end = X;;
module Y : sig type t = int val x : int end
# [X.x; Y.x];;
- : int list = [42; 42]
```